# Insert in two tables continuously from one form in CakePHP

Tags: database, forms, cakephp, insert

I have two tables with the following variables:

**Table1(Users):**
ID, fName,lName

**Table2(Details):**
table1ID, Age, DOB

Here is my Form in view:

```
<form action="/admin/users/add" id="WordAdminAddForm" method="post">
    <input type="text" name="data[text1][fName]" >
    <input type="text" name="data[text1][lName]" >
    <input type="text" name="data[text2][Age]" >
    <input type="text" name="data[text2][DOB]" >
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Add New User')); ?>
```

I want to insert the *fname* and *lname* in the *first table* and then retriving the ID and put the ID, Age and DOB in the second table, just by one time pressing the submit button.

* The ID is Auto increment

**Update**

Here is my Model

```
class User extends AppModel {
    public $displayField = 'fName';
    public $hasMany = array('Detail');

    public $validate = array(
        'fName' => 'notEmpty',
        'lName' => 'notEmpty'
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$data1 = $this->request->data['text1'];
$data2 = $this->request->data['text2'];

$profile= $this->Profiles->newEntity();
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        $profile = $this->Profiles->patchEntity($profile, $data1);
        if ($this->Profiles->save($data1)) {
            //get return id from first table
            $data2['tabelA_id'] = $profile->id;
            insert into 2nd table
            $profileChild = $this->ProfileChilds->newEntity();
            $profileChild = $this->ProfileChilds->patchEntity($profileChild, $data2);
        }
?>
```

or you can define relationship hasOne in the model. Cakephp will automatically insert into second table.
http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html

Answer (score 0):

try this simple code its works for you.

```
       if(!empty($this->data))
       {
            $this->User->create();
            $fName= $this->data['text1']['fName'];
            $lName=$this->data['text1']['lName'];

            $data = array(
                    "fName"=>$fName,
                    "lName"=>$lName,

                );
            $list=$this->User->save($data);

            $this->Detail->create();
            $Age= $this->data['text2']['Age'];
            $DOB=$this->data['text2']['DOB'];

            $data_list= array(
                    "Age"=>$Age,
                    "DOB"=>$DOB,
                    "table1ID"=>$list['User']['ID'],

                );
            $this->Detail->save($data_list);
        }
```

Comment: Do I have to put this code in add() on UserController? please look at the Model that I added. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I don't know which version of cake you use, but here it is for 2.x

In your controller, simply save your new user, then use the field id to save the details

```
//save the user
$this->User->create();
$this->User->save($this->request->data['text1']);
//create the new details with the user id
$newDetail = $this->request->data['text2']);
$newDetail['table1ID'] = $this->User->id
//save the new details
$this->Detail->create();
$this->Detail->save($newDetail);
```